# when trying to write a table to csv, an error occurs

Tags: r, csv

Error when writing dataframe to csv file

```
write.csv(data, "data.csv")
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'torg_acq_view1.csv': Invalid argument
```

I found a solution to the problem, so I want to share.
Before writing a table to a file, you must close all connections with the command `closeAllConnections()`

Example

```
closeAllConnections()
write.csv(data, "data.csv")
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm sorry.  the problem arose while writing a script in R language